# Can't use mouse to place an insertion point or drag-select text in Word; cursor moves as commanded by mouse

Tags: microsoft-word

My cursor moves okay, as commanded by the mouse, but, in MS Word, I can't place an insertion point nor can I drag-select text.  Also, I have to shut down Word using Alt+F4, since shutting down with the X in the upper right corner generates a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution online, WHICH WORKED!!!
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/940791/how-do-i-fix-the-problem-that-i-experience-after-i-install-an-automati?spid=11377    Make sure you backup the Registry before you start; you can do this by following directions at:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows